# Setting optional method arguments?

Tags: ruby, recursion

I am trying to define a method to sum the elements of a given array. So far I have:

```
def sum2
  return self if self.length <=1
  i = self.length
  @sum2 = sum2(i-1) + self[i]
end
```

I'm getting an invalid argument error for the second call of `sum2(i-1)`. Is there any way I can set it to take either 0 or 1 arguments? Or, am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear from the question phrasing, but I assume `sum2` is a method in an array class that you've defined yourself. So, I assume it's derived from a Ruby Array class.

Currently, your method returns the array `self` if it has no more than one element. Technically, the array of one element isn't the sum of elements. So you don't want to return `self` in that case.

But you can use Ruby's array methods to simplify:

```
def sum2
  self.inject(:+)
end
```

This will return `nil` if the array has zero length, and the sum of elements otherwise. If you want to return `0` on a length `0` array, then:

```
def sum2
  return (self.length == 0) ? 0 : self.inject(:+)
end
```

Or more simply, per @toro2k's comment:

```
def sum2
  self.inject(0, :+)
end
```

Comment: To return 0 for an empty array you can pass two arguments to `inject`: `inject(0, :+)`.